# psycopg2.extras.execute_values gives “AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'encoding'”

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to migrate data from one table to another. First, I read data from table and store result in table_data variable.

```
table_data = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'abcd', 'auto_provision': True, 'created_at': '2021-01-21 00:14:16.1611188056', 'updated_at': None, 'endpoint': '10.10.01.10', 'username': 'asd', 'password': 'xyz'}]
```

now I am writing that data to another table, code is here

```
        """
        write into pg_shard table 
        """
        with pg.get_session_sn(dbname, pg_cfg) as sn:
        column_names = ",".join(list(table_data[0].keys()))
            q_insert = 'INSERT INTO table_x ({}) VALUES %s'.format(column_names)
            execute_values(
                sn,
                q_insert,
                argslist=[list(v.values()) for v in table_data],
                template=None,
                page_size=100
            )
        return
    except Exception as error:
        log.error(error)
    finally:
        if sn is not None:
            sn.close()
            log.info('\nDatabase connection closed')
```

this code is giving me     `"AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'encoding'"` 
I am thinking it's because "argslist" value. But then I tried to convert it as string but still not working. Any idea, how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What's the full traceback of the error?

Comment: I have fixed this issue by using     ```cursor_factory=RealDictCursor``` while creating connection with postgres using psycopg2.